# Load Text File Into Object in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, ioexception

I am trying to write a class but running into problems. The problem I am having is I need to read in a text file and return it back out of the method. I am stuck with many errors. Could anyone help me with this?

The text file looks like this

Question 1

Answer 1

Question 2

Answer 2

Question 3

Answer 3

....

etc.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Quiz {

    private String fName; // Name of the file you will be reading from
    private Scanner theFile; // Scanner use to read from the file
    public int status = 0;
    public String line = null;
    public int i = 0;

    // Create a new Quiz object by opening the associated file. Note that this
    // method throws an IOException, so in the method that calls it you must
    // also
    // have in the header "throws IOException". We will discuss how to handle
    // these exceptions later.
    public Quiz(String f) throws IOException {

        File Quiz = new File(f);
        Scanner theFile = new Scanner(Quiz);
        theFile.close();
        return Quiz;
    }

    // First check the status. If it is 1 or 2 simply return false.
    // If it is 0, check the file:
    // If there is a line in the file, return true
    // If there is no line in the file, set status to 1 and
    // return false.
    public boolean hasAQuestion() {
        if (status == 1 || status == 2) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (status == 0) {
            if (line = theFile.readLine() != null) {
                return true;
            }
            else if (line = theFile.readLine() == null) {
                status = 1;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // Return that status of the Quiz object:
    // Status = 0: everything ok
    // Status = 1: end of file reached
    // Status = 2: error has occurred
    public int getStatus() {
        if (line = theFile.readLine() != null) {
            status = 0;
        }
        else if (line = theFile.readLine() == null) {
            status = 1;
        }
        else if (line.theFile.readLine() == " ") {
            status = 2;
        }
        return status;
    }

    // Get the next question and set the status appropriately:
    // If status is not 0, return null, otherwise:
    // If no lines are left before anything is read, set status
    // to 1 and return null
    // If the question is read but no answer left, set status to
    // to 2 and return null
    // If both the question and answer are read, return them in
    // a new Question object.

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors/exceptions do you have? on what line?

Comment: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value is for the return value in the method public Quiz(String f)

Comment: and then i get a cannot find symbol for every line in the hasAQuestion() method and getStatus() method

Comment: You need to start small.  Write a simple class with a simple constructor.  You'll learn that you cannot return a value from a constructor.  Then move on adding attributes, methods and so forth.  While syntactically allowed, please don't use the name of your class as the name for a local variable.  It is most confusing.

Comment: How would I go about reading in a file, storing it in an object, and returning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly,

```
File Quiz = new File(f);
```

is not a good practice. `Quiz` is the name of a class. `File` is also the name of a class. If you want to create a File object, do this:

```
File quizFile = new File(f);
```

You shouldn't want to create a Quiz object *within* the Quiz constructor, as the constructor will call the Quiz constructor... and you get stuck with an infinite loop. This is probably just a naming mistake, but remember not to start variable names with capital letters and also avoid having a file object names quiz within a Quiz class, because that leads to some confusion.

So anyway your error comes from this line:

```
theFile.close();
```

What you just did here is that you created a Scanner object, opening a stream to read from the text file, then closed it. So now its not possible for you to read from the file, because you just closed your stream. The solution to this would be to have a `close()` method within the Quiz class to be invoked by some other class once it is done reading from the file.

Finally,

```
return Quiz;
```

Constructors don't return anything. They just construct an object of the class. Also, I'm not entirely sure but you might be confused between what a class is and what an object is. A class is just like a template for an object; the things that an object can do and what attributes it has is defined by a class. For example, in the statement

```
Cat bob = new Cat();
```

You are creating an object (bob) of the class Cat.

The statement `return Quiz;`, even if it were not in a constructor, means nothing because you are returning a *class* not an object. If you want a static method to return an object, then it should be something along the lines of

```
return new Cat();
```

not
    return Cat;

Comment: Actually, the first line is valid from a language point of view.  Java has different namespaces for types and variables.  `class X { X X() { X X = new X(); return X; } }` is valid (tough extremely poor style) Java.

Comment: I did not actually, know that will update answer. Thanks for the information.

Comment: First off, thank you for explaining so well. I changed everything you said and got all my errors to go away except one.                                error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
  return new File();

Comment: Where is this error thrown? If you are attempting to return a File object from the constructor, then like I said that is invalid. The error is probably because you are returning a File object from a method that is defined to return an object of another class.

Comment: This is the line in the main program that calls that method "Q = new Quiz("questions.txt");" Quiz Q; is stated right above that line. I'm not sure what it is wanting back from that method.

Comment: It should tell you which line within the constructor is breaking. Otherwise I'm not entire sure what the issue can be. Check to make sure you aren't doing something like `SomeClass s = new File(str)` where SomeClass is a class other than File.

Comment: That was it. I copied a line from a different part and forget to change the name. Thank You So Much for you help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public Quiz(String f) throws IOException
{

    File Quiz = new File(f);
    Scanner theFile = new Scanner(Quiz);
    theFile.close();
    return Quiz;
}
```

You're trying to return an object from a constructor, and you can't do that.

Also, `theFile.readLine()` - `Scanner` doesn't have readLine() method, only `nextLine()`